# Create xls file upon sending a form in php

Tags: php, excel, xls

I need to create .xls file upon sending a php form in php.
What I managed to do so far is to have a csv file created wchich works fine,but for tech specifications I need to change it to .xls
Here's the code I have so far, for the csv creation:

```
$filename = "documentname.csv";


$file = fopen($filename, 'w');     
fprintf($file, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF)); // fixing the utf8 thing


// Column names
$cells[] = array('Title', 'Type', 'Address', 'Phone', 'Email');

// Data
$cells[] = array($_POST['title'], $_POST['type'], $_POST['address'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['email']);

foreach($cells as $cell){
    fputcsv($file,$cell);
} 
fclose($file);
```

Like I said, that exports the data to csv without problems, but I need to change it to xls. Is there an easy way to do that?Do note that I need utf8 characters to be shown in the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can using PHPExcel lib for that.
Look at [PHPExcel on github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)